# Swift closure as values in Dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, closures

I'm trying to use an Objective-C library which expects a `NSDictionary` as its return type. Within the `NSDictionary`, I can return values of any type, including blocks.

I cannot figure out if there is a way to write an analogous swift method that returns a Dictionary with a closure or a string as a possible value type.

I can't use `AnyObject` as the value type for the dictionary so this doesn't work:

```
Dictionary<String,AnyObject> = ["Key":{(value:AnyObject) -> String in return value.description]
```

I get a `Does not conform to protocol error` from the compiler regarding the closure and `AnyObject`.

Is there a higher level type or protocol that both closures and basic types adhere to that I can use as the value type in a Dictionary?

Comment: the closures are not `AnyObject` types. the closures are closures, therefore the correct syntax'd be: `let mydictionary: Dictionary<String, (value: AnyObject) -> String> = ["Key":{ (value: AnyObject) -> String in return value.description}]`; hint: you can make your life easier, with using `typealias`... and I should have created an answer instead of a comment...

Comment: @holex this would allow him to only put closures in the dictionary, but would not allow him to put strings in it, which I think was OP's question.

Comment: @David, that is true, for achieving that, the `valueType` should be `Any` only instead.

Comment: @holex I'm not sure any works either.  In my experiments it crashes Xcode on beta 3.

Comment: @David, to be fair, I have not tried to compile it (my bad), but syntactically looked correct to me.

Comment: @holex: In the Swift book, "Type Casting" section, it says "Any can represent an instance of any type at all, apart from function types."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your basic problem is that in Objective-C closures (aka blocks) are represented as NSObject (or more precisely are transparently converted to NSObjects) while in Swift there is no such mapping.  This means that closures can not be directly stored in a Dictionary (short of using objective-c glue)

The closest I can come up with is something along the lines of wrapping the value in an enum:

```
enum DataType {
    case AsString(String)
    case AsClosure((AnyObject)->String)
}

var dict:Dictionary<String,DataType> = [
    "string":DataType.AsString("value"),
    "closure":DataType.AsClosure({(argument:AnyObject) -> String in
        return "value"
        }
    )
]
```

Which is probably a better solution anyway, because this way you have an explicit typing associated with individual arguments instead of it being implicit using some sort of inflection.

Alternatively, you could only wrap the closure and use a dictionary of type `Dictionary<String,Any>`.

Comment: Not how I would have preferred to solve the problem but it seems the best solution available right now.

Comment: I've added a solution below which uses generics, removing the need for an `enum` for each type. Mostly for dealing with `NSDictionary` though, not `Dictionary` (since you can use `Any`, as mentioned above).

Answer (score 3):

If you still need a workaround, here is one; usage looks like this:

```
var d : [String : AnyObject] = [:]
d["a"] = Blocks.voidBlockToId({ println("Doing something") })
d["b"] = "Some string"
d["c"] = Blocks.intBlockToId({ i in println("Called with integer: \(i)") })

Blocks.toIntBlock(d["c"])(1)
Blocks.toVoidBlock(d["a"])()
println(d["b"])
```

Output is:

1. Called with integer: 1
2. Doing something
3. Some string

The `Blocks` class is defined like this in Objective-C (with corresponding header and bridging header, I won't put those here):

```
typedef void(^VoidBlock)(void);
typedef void(^IntBlock)(int);

@implementation Blocks

+ (id) voidBlockToId: (VoidBlock) block { return block; }
+ (VoidBlock) toVoidBlock: (id) block { return (VoidBlock)block; }

+ (id) intBlockToId: (IntBlock) block { return block; }
+ (IntBlock) toIntBlock:(id)block { return (IntBlock)block; }

@end
```

You also need to add a new `xyzBlockToId` and `toXyzBlock` method for every new closure-type you want to use. It's pretty ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is another type, `Any`, that object, structs and primitives all conform to but functions do not. There is no general function type, but you can describe a function type as its arguments and return value like this:

```
Dictionary<String, (AnyObject) -> String>
```

[Function Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_229)

Comment: As noted above in comments to @holex, this will only closures to be stored in the dictionary, and specifically only closures matching a specific signature.

Comment: That's true. Is that not what he's looking for? Function Types don't inherit from Any or any other more general protocol.

Comment: I'm not positive, but it reads to me as if he's looking for something that will at a minimum store strings and closures.

Comment: Ah you're right. Unfortunately, there isn't a type or protocol that both String and function types conform to

Answer (score 0):

Could you use an `NSMutableDictionary`?

Alternatively, this seemed to work for me using your example:

```
1> import Foundation
2> var myDict: [String: (NSObject) -> String] = ["Key":{(value:NSObject) -> String in return value.description}]
myDict: [String : (NSObject) -> String] = {
  [0] = {
    key = "Key"
    value =
  }
}
3> myDict["Key"]!("Testing")
```

> $R2: String = "Testing"

Hmm, maybe this Swift-Code doesn't really help, because you want to have heterogenous dictionaries.

It's also not possible to put closures into an `NSDictionary`, it seems (as a closure does not conform to `AnyObject`).

Answer (score 0):

You could also roll your own higher type using an `enum`. You need the dictionary values to be either strings or functions which return strings, so define a type to represent that:

```
enum MyDictVal {
  case ValString(String)
  case ValFunc(AnyObject -> String)
}
```

Then, you can put it in a dictionary:

```
let d: Dictionary<String, MyDictVal> = [
  "a": .ValString("a")
, "b": .ValFunc({ (value) in value.description })
]
```

Then you'll need to process the dictionary values using pattern matching:

```
switch d["b"] {
  case .ValString(let s):
    ...
  case .ValFunc(let f):
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more "generic" solution which should work with `Any` object, but shown with closures and function references.  Drop it into a playground and try it out!

```
// Wrapper for sticking non-objects in NSDictionary instances
class ObjectWrapper {
    let value: T
    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

// convenience to downcast `as! ObjectWrapper` and return its value
func getValueFromObjectWrapper(a: AnyObject) -> T {
    return (a as! ObjectWrapper).value
}

func wrappedObjectsInDictionary() -> NSDictionary {
    var dict = NSMutableDictionary()
    let appendToFoo: (String) -> String = NSString.stringByAppendingString("foo")
    let firstChar: (String) -> Character = { $0[$0.startIndex] }
    dict.setObject(ObjectWrapper(firstChar), forKey: "stringToChar")
    dict.setObject(ObjectWrapper(appendToFoo), forKey: "stringTransformer")
    return dict.copy() as! NSDictionary
}

let dict = wrappedObjectsInDictionary()
let appendToFoo: (String) -> String = getValueFromObjectWrapper(dict["stringTransformer"]!)
let strToChar: (String) -> Character = getValueFromObjectWrapper(dict["stringToChar"]!)

appendToFoo("bar") // "foobar"
strToChar("bar") // "b"
```