# How do I achieve the flexibility below in Swift: effectively a variable capable of holding a fairly "generic" function

Tags: swift

I need to create a construct to hold a fairly generalised function. The argument types can be any permutation of Double|String|Bool in the input and output.

Effectively, at compile time I do NOT know what precise type my function will be other than that it will be some combination of Double|String|Bool in its input & output parameters. This precise signature will be only known at run-time.

```
enum S{
    case Double
    case String
    case Bool
}

enum T{
    case Double
    case String
    case Bool
}

typealias F = S -> T

var f:F = exp  //compile-time error
f(30.0) //compile-time error
```

The last two lines above are where the error comes as it seems to want the type of f to be explicitly a Double/Float-like type.

Just to be clear: my question is specifically what kind of generalised Swift construct I can use to store the "exp" function in until I later need to invoke it?

I intend to generalise the solution to two and more inputs parameters later making brute force enumeration of all the options of function signatures not such a great solution. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift closure as values in Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635202/swift-closure-as-values-in-dictionary)

Comment: Although your question isn't an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635202/swift-closure-as-values-in-dictionary/24636856#24636856, I think the answer is going to be pretty similar.  More specifically you're going to want your functions to take values wrapped in enums with associated values and go from there.